# Monitoring Quartz Scheduler to warn about jobs that haven't ran

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I currently have some quartz jobs running and I'd like to set up some monitoring that would send out alerts if a job fails to run.  I know if a job fails quartz can send out notifications but what I am looking for is some that could warn me if the quartz thread itself bombed out and just quit running jobs altogether (as an example).

My though was to just compare Quartz's schedule with a list of what has ran successfully.  From looking at the API's it looks like I can easily fetch the schedule information so that I know what **should** have run.  The trick is figuring out what **has** run.  Am I missing something in the API's?  I see some plug-ins that provide java.logging logs of what has ran and when but nothing that I could pull from the database.

If nothing else it looks like I could modify that class to push some information to a database and go from there but I'd prefer not to duplicate any of this if I don't have to.

Thanks! 
Jason

Answer (score 1):

May be i misunderstand what you like to reach but what about the [Job Listeners](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson07.html) for example

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the LoggingJobHistoryPlugin (the logging plugin I referred to above) uses the Job listener.  This is what I was looking at as far as storing the "what ran" part if I were to implement this.  What I am trying to figure out is if there is something already built that does this.  Seems like it would be a commonly requested feature.  That is the ability query what ran when and the success/failure of the job.